# how to use graphql in nestjs micro-service?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, graphql-js, nestjs-microservice

how to use graphql in nestjs micro-service?

we all know that graphql could be used with http.

but coult it use by micro-service like nestjs micro-service?

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport, MicroserviceOptions } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        port: 23001,
      },
    },
  );
  await app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

we all know graphql in nestjs should build resolver, but micro service sould use controller with MessagePattern and EventPattern.

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, it could be used. But there's a plenty of reasons why it shouldn't. Extra complexity, strict coupling with backend app, not that easy transformation to other messaging protocols (like from HTTP to MQ - REST has a structure easily serializable to anything that's not REST).

But yes, it's possible. GraphQL operates on JSON request bodies, and on JSON responses. So that'd be either some custom parsing inside regular controllers, or rewriting whole microservices logic to fit it Apollo or Mercurius - alongside execution context, etc.

That's not worth it :) And I'm saying that, I love GraphQL :)